# PHP $_GET["action"] method in href not working

Tags: php, html

I have a html href like this

```
<td colspan="5" align="right" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><a href="index.php?action=createtopic"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </a></td>
```

but when i used it

```
if ($_GET["action"]=="createtopic")
```

it throws an error :  Undefined index: action in "C:...."

Comment: Has the code `if ($_GET...)` inside the same file as the link/anchor/href?

Comment: Is the php code on the same page as the link ?

Comment: Yes... everything is inside the index.php including the php code and the form which should display if the href is clicked

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `$_GET['action']` is set, for that you can use [isset()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if( isset( $_GET["action"] ) )
{
    if( $_GET["action"] == "createtopic" )
    {
       # do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your answer since you can do it all in the same if statement without any loss of performance because if it is not set it will not check for the next argument anyway